# funny characters in Sql String

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a `query string` that works fine if `tableStr` is for example `MSFT`. However, if tableStr is `BRK-B`, the `query` fails.

```
    string query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableStr + " where DATE(Date) >= " + "'" + howFarBack.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: You need to enclose the table name.  From what I have read, using back ticks is the correct approach.  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html), "The identifier quote character is the backtick (`)".

This means that if your table name has special characters in it, you need to surround the identifier with backticks. To avoid SQL injection problems, you should also escape all backticks `` ` `` by converting them to double backticks ``` `` ```.

For all other parameters, use command parameters to avoid SQL injection.

```cs
using var cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `" + tableStr.Replace("`", "``") + "` where DATE(Date) >= @howFarBack";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@howFarBack", howFarBack);
```